# managedQuery not closed cursor onDestroy?

Tags: android, cursor

I have run into a problem I don't understand. I'm using managedQuery with the only Cursor of an activity and when I quit the activity (the app in this case), I get the following error printed in logcat :

> I/dalvikvm(  420): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
>
> I/dalvikvm(  420):
> Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;:
> Finalizing cursor
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@437b5f10
> on contacts that has not been
> deactivated or closed
>
> I/dalvikvm(
> 420):     at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
>
> I/dalvikvm(  420):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native
> Method)

I was supposing that calling managedQuery would have close the cursor before. What am I missing here ?

**EDIT:**

This not on close but on re-open but this doesn't change anything to the problem, the cursor is not finalized on previous close

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are overriding an Activity lifecycle method (onClose, onDestroy, etc.) and failing to call the same method of the superclass.